# Null pointer Exception Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bundler

Am passing a string from on activity to another, its working but if i try and open the activity without passing the strings It throws a Null pointer exception, Kindly Assit

```
    Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    gotPassenger= gotBasket.getString("passenger");
    gotStaffNumber= gotBasket.getString("clientcode");
    etPassenger.setText(""+ gotPassenger );
    etStaffNumber.setText("" + gotStaffNumber);
```

Comment: where are you getting null pointer exception. post some more details.

Answer (score 5):

> if i try and open the activity without passing the strings It throws a Null pointer exception

right, becuase you didnt send any data

check if the gotBasket is **NULL** before assigning

like this:

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
if(gotBasket != null){
    gotPassenger= gotBasket.getString("passenger");
    gotStaffNumber= gotBasket.getString("clientcode");
    etPassenger.setText(""+ gotPassenger );
    etStaffNumber.setText("" + gotStaffNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
```

better use this:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtras("passenger")){
//get Extras here
}
```

That way, you wont get **NPE** as you only try to get the Bundle Extras only if they were passed